# Automation error when deleting sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a little sub to delete specific sheets, according to a form display to the user. The user choose which sheet he wants to keep in a listbox. The code then loop through all the sheets in the listbox and delete the sheets that are not selected.
But, when running the form and click on the button I got an automation error :

> Execution error '-2147417848 (80010108):
>   Automation Error
>   object invoked has disconnected

```
Private Sub Button_Export_Click()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 0 To PSV_Case_List.listCount - 1
        If Not PSV_Case_List.Selected(i) Then
            Worksheets(PSV_Case_List.List(i)).Delete

        End If
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Following this message, Excel freezes and I have to kill the process.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

When you do deletes like this, you should allways start with the highest index and work your way down, because as soon as sheet(0) is deleted, sheet(1) becomes sheet(0) and so on. So try this:

```
For i = PSV_Case_List.listCount - 1 to 0 step -1
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. In fact, as PSV_Case_List.List(i) contains the name of the sheet and is not affected when I deleted sheets, as it is the contents of the List Box. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you tried to save it in an array then delete it after the form is closed? Just open the form, select the superstite sheet, click ok, close form, delete every sheet in the array list. Maybe deleting it with the form open would cause the form to disappear then the "object will be disconnected".Anyway in that case you could just debug for see when the macro fail.